# userActivity.search in Google Analytics Data API v1

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, userinfo

I was using `userActivity.search` method in **Google Analytics Reporting API v4** by providing a UserID (ga cookie). Is there any similar way in the new GA Data API?

In Google Analytics GA 4>Explore>User Explorer you can see the data of the users and their user ids, which are the _ga cookies.
Here is the link to the old method which I have been using till Google stopped supporting it: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search#http-request
Thank you